# How to Verify the string / text by using Protractor

Tags: protractor

I want to verify that one screen string value with other screen string value. For example, if I try to select one product from the product list screen, the product detail screen is opened which is selected from the list. In this case, I want to verify the product name whether the selected product and opened product is the same or not by using protractor.

This is my Code:

```
productName = element(by.css('.item_name .ng-binding')).get(value).filter(function(text)
{
   if(productName.getText() == element.all(by.css('.LinesEllipsis')).get(1))
   {
      productName.click();
      expect(element.all(by.css('.LinesEllipsis')).get(1).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I am reading the question wrong. Can't you store the strings in a variable and later compare them and make sure it is same ?

Comment: Sorry Bro, Before I update wrong code now  I changed. Please check once and tell me what mistake I did here.

Comment: It this code throwing an error?  If so, please post  that too.  At a glance, it doesn't look like you have your declaration closed properly:  `productName = element(by.css('.item_name .ng-binding')).get(value).filter(function(text))`.  You are missing a ')' it looks like to me.

Comment: What is 'get(value)' here? There are multiple syntax issues with this code.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to the Protractor but in our software quality assurance company many teams are working on the protractor and I had faced the similar issues while automating the tests and had taken their help on the same. Hopefully below code snippet will work.

```
productName = element(by.css('.item_name .ng-binding')).get(value).filter(function(text)
{
   if(productName.getText() == element.all(by.css('.LinesEllipsis')).get(1))
   {
      productName.click();
expect(element.all(by.css('.LinesEllipsis')).get(1).isPresent()).toBe(true);
   }
}
```

Please do share your code with error if below code is not working.
Thanks